# Is Fermat's theorem about local extrema true for smooth manifolds?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f\colon M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function.

If $p\in M$ is a local extremum of $f$, does $p$ have to be a critical point?

Comment: Local extrema and critical point are both local properties, which means it's enough to look at an $\Bbb R^n$-neighbourhood of $p$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Actually, we necessarily have $df_p=0$. To see this, let $\gamma$ be an arbitrary path passing through $p$ at time $0$. Then $$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}(f\circ\gamma)=0,$$and so$$df_p(v)=0,$$where $v$ is the tangent vector represented by $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.  Another way to see this is as follows.

If $p$ is a local extremum of $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$, choose a coordinate neighborhood $(U, \phi)$ for $p$.  Then the map $f |_U \circ \phi^{-1}$ has a local extremum at $\phi(p)$.  Computing $df|_p$ in these coordinates shows that it's $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This is exactly the Lagrange Multiplier Criterion for functions restricted to a smooth manifold (the constraint set). Jerry Shurman's book *Multivariate Calculus* available for free at
https://www.professores.uff.br/diomarcesarlobao/wp-content/uploads/sites/85/2017/09/Multi_calculus_BOOK.pdf
explains this in Chapter 5 (section 5.5, especially). See also the Preface.